# I'm stuck at 99.3%

Tags: stranger-things-the-game

I'm stuck at 99.3% in Stranger Things The Game and I don't know what to do.

I have followed the tutorial on how to do it but I must be missing something.

How can I complete the missing 0.7%

Comment: Thanks for your question. Please can you add details of the tutorial you mention, so people answering can get more of an idea of what you have already tried.